# Drawing circuit for compound proposition

Tags: java, diagram, boolean-expression

I want to solve a compound proposition with parentheses and draw circuit for it.

My problem is that I don't know which algorithm is the right algorithm. I tried Abstract syntax tree but there was no conclusion.
maybe Reverse Polish notation is the right way to solve a compound proposition with parentheses but I should draw a circuit in each level and Reverse Polish notation just gives a final answer.

**Example:**

[image: Example]

** The way I think about it **

[image: The way i think about it]

Comment: Show us, what you got so far. An AST seems sensible to me since the tree (which you provided in your second link) is almost the diagramm you want (just replace some nodes by different images and you are done).

Comment: The question that you ask should be complete, without having to follow the links (at least for the main idea). Also, when asking questions, write in correct English (i => I, ...) - it makes things easier to read.

Comment: AST and RPN are not "algorithms" - an algorithm is a recipe, An AST represents a parse tree, while RPN is a (postfix) notation that allows easy stack-based expression evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

I would decompose your problem as follows:

- Write code that can parse the expression into an AST.
- Write code to draw each of the circuit symbols given a minimal AST node: NOT, OR, AND, XOR from `~A`, `A|B`, `A&B` and `A^B`, respectively
- Write code to draw the whole parse tree.

Your AST nodes could look like:

```
 public interface CircuitNode {
     // parsing-related
     String getExpression();      
     List<String> getInputNames();
     List<CircuitNode> getChildren();      
     String getOutputName();

     // drawing-related; call children to compute things and draw children
     int calculateHeight();
     int calculateWidth();
     void draw(Graphics2D g, int x, int y);

     // simulate circuit, if you need it 
     boolean simulate(boolean[] inputs);
 }
```

If you follow the decomposition steps, you would first implement the parsing-related parts of the `CircuitNode` interface (no drawing required). Then you would try to `draw` simple nodes (those that do not contain other nodes inside), which would return for example 100 for `calculateWidth` and 50 for `calculateHeight`. Finally, you would try to draw larger expressions, with implementations of `calculateHeight`, `calculateWidth` and `draw` that would use recursion to draw multi-node circuits.